# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания: «совещание проводится не реже одного раза в месяц, а может быть и чаще в зависимости от назревших вопросов»?

Answer (score 2):

Предложение построено, на мой взгляд, неудачно. Выражение НЕ РЕЖЕ уже предполагает возможность проведения совещаний чаще одного раза в месяц. Вторая часть кажется лишней. Предложение требует правки.
***«Совещания проводятся в зависимости от количества назревших вопросов, но не реже одного раза в месяц»***. Может быть, не самый удачный вариант, но всё-таки лучше первого.

Answer (score 0):

Совещание проводится не реже одного раза в месяц, а может быть, и чаще, в зависимости от назревших вопросов. Вводная конструкция выделяется запятой вместе с союзом "а", если при удалении вводных слов не нарушается смысл и структура предложения. Запятой после слова "чаще" следует выделить уточняющее обстоятельство.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, если имеется в виду - а может проводиться и чаще.

Запятая нужна, если имеется в виду - а кажется, и чаще.

Comment: ошибка в слове проводится, надо - а может проводиться и чаще